# aliases not picked up when sudo in mac?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, alias

I have the following aliases in `/etc/profile`.

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

alias startapache="/usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.29/bin/apachectl start"
alias stopapache="/usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.29/bin/apachectl stop"

alias ll='ls -lG'
```

I just added the last three aliases. Now when I do

`sudo su`: I dont get these aliases picked up.

```
sh-3.2# startapache
sh: startapache: command not found
```

but when I am **not sudoing**, I get this aliases (This is bash shell). But it does not start apache.

```
local:~ 112019$ startapache 
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Comment: The title of this question seems to say that it's about an OS X system, and some of the details suggest this also. (For example, Mac users often put aliases in "profile" files as they often don't readily see how this is unreliable, which in turn is because Terminal.app starts a login shell, which is unusual for a graphical terminal except in OS X. And running `sudo su` gives a shell with a very basic prompt, which isn't usually what happens when that's run in Ubuntu.) If this question is asking about an OS X system and not an Ubuntu system, we should close it, then possibly migrate to Unix.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` shell only reads `/etc/profile` when invoked as a *login shell*, which `su` does not normally do - you would need to invoke `su` with the `-`, `-l`, or `--login` option. From `man su`:

```
   -, -l, --login
       Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
       the user logged in directly.

       When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option. The
       other forms (-l and --login) do not have this restriction.
```

See `man bash` for full details about which startup files are read by interactive login, interactive non-login, and non-interactive shells.

Comment: ok, I followed `sudo su -l` and it seems to pick up alias.

Answer (score 0):

To make those aliases available for `root`, you can put them into `/root/.bash_aliases`.

However, if you just need to run those aliases as `root` from your user, you can just put them into `~/.bash_aliases` and add `sudo` at the start of each alias' command:

```
alias startapache="sudo /usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.29/bin/apachectl start"
alias stopapache="sudo /usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.29/bin/apachectl stop"
alias ll='sudo ls -lG'
```

Also I didn't notice this at first, but using `ll` as an alias for `ls -lG` would overwhelm the deafult `ll` alias' behavior either if set in  `/root/.bash_profile` and if set in `~/.bash_profile`, where it's set as an alias of `ls -la`: so unless you want to overwhelm `ll`'s alias behavior for the user you'll end up adding those aliases for, you should change its name to something else, e.g. to `lg`:

```
alias lg='sudo ls -lG'
```

Comment: Making a common `ls` alias like `ll` run `ls` with `sudo` seems like a bad idea, since `ls` needn't/shouldn't be run as root when not necessary, and because having it run as root when that's not expected [would be weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). (Specifically, the user may be confused as to why they are being prompted for a password, or may be confused about why they cannot `cd` to a directory they appear to be able to `ls`.) If an alias to run `sudo ls -lG` is needed, I'd suggest one of a different name--maybe called it `sll`.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks, I didn't notice this